# Could not load assembly during runtime although binding redirect is correctly set

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, assembly-binding-redirect

I have a **unit test project .NET 4.6.1** where some tests fail prolly because I added a new project as a new reference to the unit test project.

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error: System.IO.FileLoadException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.1.1.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies.
 The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).
```

Then I added this configuration to the **app.config** of the **unit test project:**

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.1.0" newVersion="1.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

But the test still fails with SAME error messsage.

Why did the binding redirect not help?

I have of course also these props in the unit test .csproj file:

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
```

When I check the generated unit.test.config file in the debug folder it does contain many binding redirects BUT not the one why my tests fail...

Just discovered this in the output box after rebuild solution:

NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection from 2.2.0 to 1.1.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.

```
 UnitTests -> MyNewReferencedProject -> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService 2.14.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (>= 2.2.0) 

 UnitTests -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (>= 1.1.1)
```

Is this "warning" related to my problem in any way because my problem is about assembly `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions`

and **not** about `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

I have these assembly versions of the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractons.dll in all debug\bin folders of my solution projects.

It seems I have 3 different versions floating around...

[image]

This is really funky... when I add now this binding redirect:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

The former runtime exception is gone because I get a new one.

It seems I fixed it but... this is wonky tonky stuff. Random shit...

Why was it fixed using 2.1.0.0 ???

**@Mark Gravell**

There is no inner exception its NULL.

Thats the message:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

odd is my tests are not really executed I mean I can not debug them. They just start and immediatelly I get this exception face slammed!

Comment: "or one of its dependencies". The usual culprits and Unsafe, Vectors, ValueTuple and Buffers. If you catch the exception, is there a type load failure somewhere in the inner-exception tree?

Comment: just a second I will remove the binding redirect and check that!

Comment: see my answer updated in the question! And if its usual culprits why does Microsoft not fix that xxxx? :-)

Comment: Oh, is this a unit test project, so a DLL? Yeah, full transitive dependency redirect generation doesn't work in this case. It is a known problem. I managed to get some interest from Microsoft into fixing it about a month ago, but we're nowhere near that "landing". Right now, you'll probably need explicit package references here - transitive doesn't work for anything OOB.

Comment: " you'll probably need explicit package references here" above I stated the binding redirect which fixed it with 2.1.0.0 redirect see above :-) my question is just not answered WHY 2.1.0.0 ???

Comment: The 2.1.0.0 *is* odd, because from what I can see you *should* need 2.2.0.0. As for "wonky tonky stuff. Random shit" - yes, you're absolutely right, which is part of why they fixed this later; the fix is called ".NET Core" (or ".NET 5"). Assembly binding redirects basically go away, because it was pure pain. Unit tests are *particularly* vulnerable here, because they are dlls, and the "bait and switch" step of transitive dependency resolution *doesn't happen for dlls* (it happens for apps, not libs); also, there is a known bug in the auto-generate code that means it doesn't always work...

Comment: ...correctly for transitive dependencies; this *might* get fixed - I had an extended conversation with the folks who maintain that piece of the build engine a month or so back, and they made some real progress, but it will probably only apply for newer SDKs (for example .NET 5) when targeting TFMs like net461, which means "not today"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seemed to have fixed it but its not logical to me.

```
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```